# Is there a gulp plugin to compile files contents to base64?

Tags: automation, gulp, continuous-integration, base64

I have several html templates I require to "compile" and convert to base64 format. By compile I mean injecting JS and CSS inline, and then converting it to base64 format.

I tried `gulp-base64` but that only works for images in CSS. Any ideas?

Edit: I just got an idea that maybe I could use `gulp-foreach` to process each file individually and then use a `Buffer` to convert each file's content's to base64 format. I know I could do something like:

```
> console.log(new Buffer("Hello World").toString('base64'));
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
> console.log(new Buffer("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'))
Hello World
```

But I'm not really sure how to do it since I don't understand quite well how file streams (I think it's called vinyl) work yet in gulp. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while looking for a solution to the same problem. Your suggestion to use `gulp-foreach` led me to a solution, although I didn't use that package:

```
// import the appropriate plugins
//
const each = require('gulp-each');
const htmlToJs = require('gulp-html-to-js');

// I'm compiling a couple of small PDF files
//
gulp.task('compile:pdf', () =>
    gulp.src('./files/**/*.pdf')
        // use gulp-each to iterate over the files & convert the
        // files to a base64-encoded data URL
        //
        .pipe(each((content, file, callback) => {
            const output = `data:application/pdf;base64,${new Buffer(content).toString('base64')}`;

            // the first arg in this callback is the error; the second
            // is the content to pass along via the stream
            //
            callback(null, output)
        }))

        // use gulp-html-to-js to convert the data URL to a JS module
        // which can be imported
        //
        .pipe(htmlToJs())

        // and set the destination...
        //
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/modules/helpers/files'))
);
```

The end result is a JS file with contents that look like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = 'data:application/pdf;base64,... base64 encoded string...';
```